# Add string X to string Y after certain substring

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've got two strings:
str1 is a url to controller with attributes

```
str1 = /Controller/Action?tableid=212&id=&someOtherVal=false
```

and str2 is an id value that is supposed to be added after 'id=' is str1 when changed in a field.

How do I add this ID, for example, '123' after the 'id=' in str1?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: var String  = str1 + str2 ? Or you want to first check of str1 is changed?

Comment: str1 = str1.replace(/&id=&/, '&id='+str2+'&');

Comment: @Steven No, I check if there is any value in field when I click edit button to go to this URL. I just need a method to add this ID value inside this URL after 'id='

Comment: Well check my answer, it should be exactly what you need

Answer (score 1):

I hope below snippet is what you are expecting

```
var str1 = "/Controller/Action?tableid=212&id=&someOtherVal=false";
// location.protocol + location.hostname is just to complete the URL
var urltoedit = new URL(location.protocol + location.hostname + str1);
var str2 = 123;
// check if id has value or you can modify if your condition
if(urltoedit.searchParams.get("id")=="")
{
     urltoedit.searchParams.set("id",str2);
}
// valtoset is what you need
var valtoset = urltoedit.pathname+urltoedit.search;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use replace:

```js
var val = '123';
var str1 = '/Controller/Action?tableid=212&id=&someOtherVal=false'.replace('&id=','&id='+val);

console.log(str1);
```

This will work perfect if you are sure that the `id` will be there just after the ampersand `&`. Also, you cannot simply use `replace('id=','&id=123');` as you see that the string `tableid=` will match for this and the value `123` will be replaced for `tableid` and it becomes `tableid=123`

For backup, if you think the `id` will be at the starting of the query string then you can do this:

```js
    var val = '123';
    var str1 = '/Controller/Action?tableid=212&id=&someOtherVal=false'.replace('&id=','&id='+val).replace('?id=','&id='+val);
    console.log(str1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle if id is first or last parameter and if id already have value.
Here is solution:

```
var url = "/Controller/Action?tableid=212&id=rrr&someOtherVal=false";
var parameterName = "id";
var value = "123";

function replaceParameterValueInUrl(url, parameter, value){
    var parameterStart1 = "&" + parameter + "=";
    var parameterStart2 = "?" + parameter + "=";

    //Is first parameter in URL?
    var parameterStart = url.indexOf(parameterStart1) === -1 ? parameterStart2 : parameterStart1;

    var parameterEnd = "&"; 

    var startIndex = url.indexOf(parameterStart);
    var endIndex = url.substring(startIndex + parameterStart.length).indexOf(parameterEnd);

    //Is last parameter of URL?
    if(endIndex === -1) endIndex = 0;

    var searchIndex = startIndex + endIndex;
    return url.substring(0, startIndex + parameterStart.length) + value + (endIndex === 0 ? "" : url.substring(searchIndex + parameterStart.length));
}


//Usage:
var replaced = replaceParameterValueInUrl(url, parameterName, value);
```